# create submit buttons inside php loop

Tags: php, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 $x = 5;
while($x>0)
  {
  echo 'Line' . $x;
  echo "<br>";
  $x--
  }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, along with the output i want to create 5 submit buttons. one button will be created in each iteration of the loop above. is it possible?

Comment: Why not just give it a shot?

Comment: Just `echo` out the button html code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use href will be better. if you use submit button it need create 5 different form and the code will look messy.

try this:

```
<?php
 $x = 5;
while($x>0)
  {
  echo 'Line' . $x;
  echo "<a href='test.php?a=$x'>test</a>";
  echo "<br>";
  $x--
  }

?>
```

after that :

call the value in other page :

```
if($_REQUEST['a'] == '1'){
//code here
}
else if($_REQUEST['a'] == '2'){
//code here
}

......
```

Comment: it is useful for you?

Comment: *"if you use submit button it need create 5 different form and the code will look messy."* --- Not if you place `<form></form>` tags outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just echoing `<input type=submit>`.

```
$x = 5;
while($x>0)
{
    echo 'Line' . $x;
    echo '<input type=submit value="button '.$x.'"></input>';
    echo '<br>';
    $x--
}
```

Comment: use also 'value="button'.$x.'"'

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Actually `value="button '.$x.'"`